# Oracle Instant Client issue

Tags: .net, oracle, oracle10g

I'm developing a .NET 3.5 app that will consume a oracle database... can i use the instant client that oracle give us?
If yes, How?

i downloaded it and try to add it in `References` and etc but it says that its not compatible (not COM or managed lib)...

Oracle's site is very vague and un-educative about how to get started imho

Extra Info:

- VS 2013 Update 3
- Project is .NET 3.5 x64
- Target Oracle is 10g
- instant cliente is the latest available

Comment: This is off-topic,and will probably be closed.  A quick Google search, and I found this: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-nov/o68odpnet-101744.html

Comment: i actually read and followed that article... turns out that the 64bit is a problem! If i compile for 32, it Works as intended, BUT when i compile it for Any or for x64 i get a assembly load problem saying that it (the OADP/Client) is for 32bit and I just cant "hey! let me choose which one to download!"...

Comment: You might try using 64-bit client: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html

Comment: @MarkJ.Bobak pls post your 64 bit comment as answer because i did worked out that way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compile 64-bit code, you'll need the 64-bit client, currently available here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html

If that fails to work, a Google search for 'site:oracle.com 64-bit Oracle client' should locate it for you.